# CSS wrong displaying

Tags: html, css

I want to get Div with background colored and put `#title` aligned to left and `<nav>` aligned to left and both of them in one line.

I couldn't get them into one line! And I couldn't give #Header `background-color`.

```css
/* Reset */

html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, a, p, img, ul, li, footer, fieldset, form, label, header, section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.page {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#banner {
  padding: 8em 0 5em 0;
  height: 75vh;
  background-image: url(images/banner1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#semiopacity {
  background-color: rgba(20, 15, 10, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 6em;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#header {
  padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
}

#title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 2em 0 0;
}

#lang {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<title>KAZAKHSTAN &mdash; world's large center of travel</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<div class="page">
  <section id="banner">
    <section id="semiopacity">
      <div id="Header">
        <a href="#" id="title">KAZAKHSTAN</a>
        <nav>
          <ol>
            <tr><a href="#">MAIN</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></tr>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <h1>KAZAKHSTAN</h1>
      <p>KAZAKHSTAN &mdash; WORLD'S LARGE CENTER OF TRAVEL.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section id="description">

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked `<>` and made you a snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix it:

```css
    /* Reset */
html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, a, p, img, ul, li, footer, fieldset, form, label, header, section {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.page {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#banner {
  padding: 8em 0 5em 0;
  height: 75vh;
  background-image: url(images/banner1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#semiopacity {
  background-color: rgba(20, 15, 10, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  font-family: Lato, serif;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 6em;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#header {
  padding: 1em 0 5em 0;
  background-color: rgba(20, 15, 10, 0.7);
}

#nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

#title {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 2em 0 0;
}

#lang {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
}

#buttons {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 1em 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<title>KAZAKHSTAN &mdash; world's large center of travel</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">


<div class="page">
  <section id="banner">
    <section id="semiopacity">
      <div id="Header">
        <div id="nav">
          <ol>
            <tr><a id="title" href="#">KAZAKHSTAN</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="#">MAIN</a></tr>
            <tr><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></tr>
          </ol>
        </div>

      </div>
      <h1>KAZAKHSTAN</h1>
      <p>KAZAKHSTAN &mdash; WORLD'S LARGE CENTER OF TRAVEL.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
  <section id="description">

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain the changes you made

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: THANX A LOT! ty